# Layout fill_parent / match_parent not working

Tags: android, android-layout

So I can't seem to get this empty space at the bottom of my screen out of this activity. That's how I set up my layout in the activity.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_transformer);
```

and this is my activity_transformer code. no matter what I do, I can't seem to get the empty space out! Please help. I've been searching for days now and still can't get it to work.

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".AdvancedActivity">
<com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
    android:id="@+id/slider"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    custom:pager_animation="Accordion"
    custom:auto_cycle="true"
    custom:indicator_visibility="visible"
    custom:pager_animation_span="1100"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<com.daimajia.slider.library.Indicators.PagerIndicator
    android:id="@+id/custom_indicator"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    custom:selected_color="#0095BF"
    custom:unselected_color="#55333333"
    custom:selected_drawable="@drawable/bird"
    custom:shape="oval"
    custom:selected_padding_left="5dp"
    custom:selected_padding_right="5dp"
    custom:unselected_padding_left="5dp"
    custom:unselected_padding_right="5dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    custom:selected_width="6dp"
    custom:selected_height="6dp"
    custom:unselected_width="6dp"
    custom:unselected_height="6dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    />
<com.daimajia.slider.library.Indicators.PagerIndicator
    android:id="@+id/custom_indicator2"
    style="@style/AndroidImageSlider_Corner_Oval_Orange"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />



<com.dd.CircularProgressButton
    android:id="@+id/btnWithText"
    android:layout_width="86dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="30dp"

    android:text="GO"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/slider"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<!--<ListView-->
    <!--android:layout_below="@+id/slider"-->
    <!--android:id="@+id/transformers"-->
    <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>-->
```

The buttom on the bottom should be at the very bottom.

[image]

How it looks on the preview on Android Studio

[image]

Comment: add paddingBottom to root Layout i.e RelativeLayout. and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

add the`android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to your `button` like this, and let me know it worked

```
<com.dd.CircularProgressButton
android:id="@+id/btnWithText"
android:layout_width="86dp"
android:layout_height="64dp"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:textSize="30dp"

android:text="GO"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/slider"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

and remove the `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` from the `<com.daimajia.slider.library.Indicators.PagerIndicator  />` which makes it set at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: tried but no avail. It's not really the button that's not reaching the bottom. The layout itself doesn't reach the bottom.

Comment: @user1899158 see my edited answer. Hope removing of that will fix your problem

Comment: @user1899158 what happened, did my answer solved your problem